# Fill in saved passwords after Ajax load

Tags: ajax, passwords, load, save

I'm loading a form with Ajax. I have saved a username and a password in my website. Firefox (V22) fills this in if I'm requesting the page directly, but if the form is loaded with Ajax the saved username and password will not filled in.

Is there an event I can trigger so that the saved username and password will be filled in after the Ajax load is complete?

Cheers.